# Laravel eloquent relationships user group posts

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to get the users group, and include the post on that group.

This returns the users groups, but the groups must contain the posts of the group too. a post has group_id to where it is posted

My code to get the user:

```
return User::find(1)->groups;
```

My User model:

```
public function groups()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Group');
}
```

My group model:

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Post');
}
```

Comment: If you were to do doctrine2 for example, you would not have to all this magic. You could define your relations in Annotations and have no dependencies on any parent objects (means cleaner code). You will also have better code completion and won't have to do so much with strings. You can also properly fetch your records (A user shouldn't fetch itself, Single Responsibility Principle). A model or entity should never know anything about a database.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you need: `return User::with('groups', 'groups.posts')->find(1);`

Check out nested eager loading at the bottom of the section on http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the relation to retrieve with your user, for example :

```
$user = User::with('groups')->find(1);
```

Also I would recomend to specify the keys in your relations for performance boost.

Also if you need nested with you can do this way:

```
$user = User::with('groups.posts')->find(1);
```

This will load User with groups and also posts in that group. It's stated in laravel docs. See this: [eager loading](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading)

Comment: This is the right idea, but you didn't use his example which leaves the question a bit unanswered. See my answer below.

Comment: Actually the one I am looking for is the nested with.